# Import own frameworks in Swift playground auxiliary code (under Sources)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

In a Swift playground (itself) I can use a framework which I compiled previously (and for which there is a target in Xcode workspace).

However, I am NOT able to import that framework in a Swift file which I added to the playground as auxiliary code (under Sources).

Does anyone know whether it's possible to configure framework search paths for a playground in the way so that a non-system framework can also be imported in auxiliary code of the framework?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work (yet). I dream about an additional special folder "Frameworks" , where we simply can drag and drop any framework or Xcode framework project and then, Playground would link against it.